# Accessing SQS job data (receipt handle) from a Laravel queued console command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I'm adding functionality to a pre-existing app, using Laravel 5.8.38 and the SQS queue driver.

I'm looking for a way to log the receipt handle of queue messages as they're processed, so that we can manually delete messages from the queue for jobs that have gone horribly wrong (without the receipt ID, we'd have to wait for the visibility timeout to be reached).

I'm not super familiar with Laravel and am trying to figure things out as I go. We have two types of queued jobs:

- a custom class implementing `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue`, that also uses the `Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue`, `Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable` and `Illuminate\Bus\Queueable` traits (our class gets queued directly)
- a custom command, extending `Illuminate\Console\Command`, that runs via `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand`

For the custom class, browsing through the source for `InteractsWithQueue` and `Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SqsJob` I discovered I could access the receipt handle directly:

```
$sqsJob = $this->job->getSqsJob();
\Log::info("Processing SQS job {$sqsJob["MessageId"]} with handle {$sqsJob["ReceiptHandle"]}");
```

This works great! However, I can't figure out how to do a similar thing from the console command.

Laravel's `QueuedCommand` implements `ShouldQueue` as well as `Illuminate\Bus\Queueable`, so my current guess is that I'll need to extend this, use `InteractsWithQueue`, and retrieve and log the receipt handle from there. However if I do that, I can't figure out how I would modify `Artisan::queue('app:command', $commandOptions);` to queue my custom `QueuedCommand` class instead.

Am I almost there? If so, how can I queue my custom `QueuedCommand` class instead of the Laravel one? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had just posted this question and then realised a suggestion a colleague offered provided a way forward.

So, here's my solution in case it helps anyone else!

Laravel fires a `Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing` event when processing any new queue job. I just needed to register a listener in `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected $listen = [
  'Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing' => [
    'App\Listeners\LogSQSJobDetails',
  ],
];
```

and then provide the listener to handle it:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing;

class LogSQSJobDetails
{

  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function handle(JobProcessing $event)
  {
    $sqsJob = $this->job->getSqsJob();
    \Log::info("Processing SQS job {$sqsJob["MessageId"]} with handle {$sqsJob["ReceiptHandle"]}");  
  }
}
```

This works great - and means I can also now remove the addition to my custom class from earlier.

Comment: This throws following error `ErrorException 

  Trying to access array offset on value of type null`

Comment: BTW, laravel is also firing an event after a job is queued. Ther you also have all the data you need incl. DB id. Event name: "Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobQueued"